# Using std::sort et al. with user-defined comparison routine

Tags: c++, algorithms

In the evaluator of a custom language, I would like to replace our own sort routines with `std::sort` or other routines, possibly `tbb::parallel_sort`. The problem is that we allow users of the language to supply their own comparison routine, and in the implementations I have tried, `std::sort` does not take kindly to routines that fail to be a strict order. In particular, it quickly starts looking at “elements” outside the iterator range to sort.

I assume that if I put an indirection layer on top of the iterators, I could avoid that by using virtual sentinels, but there is no reason to assume that the resulting calls would necessarily ever terminate.

So, given a black box `bool f(widget const &a, widget const &b)` and a non-user-controlled total order `operator<(widget const &a, widget const &b)`, what would be the minimal amount of calls I would need to make to get a sort call that does terminate and that does order according to `f` if that is, in fact, an order? It looks to me like the following should work, but I am hoping that I could get by with fewer calls to `f` by some clever method, possibly remembering previous comparison calls:

```
bool f_stabilized(widget const &a, widget const &b) {
  bool fab = f(a, b);
  bool fba = f(b, a);
  return (fab != fba) ? fab : (a < b);
}
```

Would it be reasonable to start out by just calling `f` and only after seeing n^2 calls for a list of length n to fall back to such a “stabilized” version? I realize that there is no reason to assume the result would be correctly ordered and I would need to start over from the beginning with such a wrapper.

Comment: "The problem is that we allow users of the language to supply their own comparison routine, and (...) std::sort does not take kindly to routines that fail to be a strict order." Okay, but what requirements on comparison routines do *you* impose for your users to satisfy? If you require strict ordering and your API users fail to provide it, it's outside of the scope of your code to try and fix it.

Comment: @Xion If the comparison routine is bad, I’m fine with not guaranteeing any kind of order. But I’m certainly not fine with crashing the interpreter with a segfault, which is what we’d currently get trying to use `std::sort` as a drop in.

Comment: What implementation of `std::sort` is that? I've had my share of bugs in comparison operators, but the only think I've ever got from `std::sort` was an assertion, never segfault and never endless loop. True, you don't want assertion either.

Comment: Nor can I imagine an implementation of sort that would run out of bounds on invalid comparison function. Normal implementation of either quick sort, merge sort nor heap sort can't do that.

Comment: Well, the `std::sort` used by clang on OS X 10.6 does, I’ve seen it in a debugger. (Who would use strict quick sort down to one-element arrays, anyway?) The low-level routines where that happens aptly have `unchecked` in their names and do things like `while (*left < foo) --left;` (quoted from memory, certainly wrong variable names). That runs out of bounds if your `<` routine actually is a `<=` operation.

Comment: I think your function is still not enough. What if you had user comparison function that claimed that a < b, b < c and c < a? Your function wouldn't fix that.

Comment: @svick True. Back to the drawing board …

Comment: std::sort requires a strict weak ordering over objects of the given type. If your sorting has a different criteria, then you need to write your own sorting algorithm. Furthermore, when would your `<` operator ever act as a `<=` operator? If your user supplied an incorrectly-behaving less-than operator, all bets should be off.

Comment: You're in for a bad time if someone provides `[](auto a, auto b) { return rand() > 0.5; }` as a comparison function.

Comment: Have you considered allowing your user to simply provide a key function instead, in the style of python's `sort(vectors, key=lambda v: v.x)`?

Comment: @JanHudec: The problem seems to be that `std::sort` invokes undefined behavior if it's preconditions are violated, wheres the OP here presumably wants to report the error to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to boil down to whether or not C++'s `std::sort` can be used with comparison functions that do not behave like the `<` operator. Operator `<` is a strict weak order, not a total order. Any container or algorithm in the C++ standard library that depends on operator `<` assume that it forms a strict weak ordering, and if you violate that assumption then havoc can ensue (as you've seen.) So, to bluntly answer the question in your title, `std::sort` works absolutely fine with custom comparator routines, but those custom routines must behave properly.

As for how to generate a proper ordering for `std::sort` given a possible total ordering, you might try the following. Given a custom ordering function `f`, define a new ordering function `f_weak` like so:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto f_weak(F comparator)
{
    return [comparator](T a, T b) {
               return comparator(a, b) // true if a <= b
                        && a != b;
    };
}
```

and then pass `f_weak<T>(f)` as the last parameter to `std::sort`. This code is untested, and uses some modern C++ features, but I'm sure you get the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, but actually, my question was if someone saw a way to encapsulate some comparator routine which is not guaranteed to be a weak order at all, such that `std::sort` is guaranteed to terminate and not crash. I guess the answer is no … (BTW, I do not understand the name `f_weak` you suggest. Shouldn't that be `f_strict` instead?)

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood your question. Yeah the answer is pretty much: use a strict weak ordering relation or expect the unexpected. As for the name `f_weak`, I called it that to express that it converts a total order into a weak order. I suppose there are plenty of more descriptive names however ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what terminology you use. In mathematics, a total order is a weak order, no conversion necessary. Actually, there are (at least?) two meanings of “weak order”: A non-strict order (which is exactly what your utility converts *from*, to a strict order), or a partial order such that incomparability is transitive – which is what I assumed you mean, since you talk about “strict weak order”. Not that I see how to even pass one to `std::sort`, since it needs to be expressed with a `bool` return type.